# How to create a single jar from multiple packages?

Tags: java

I want to create a single jar file from multiple packages. I have created the jar using below command but when I'm importing it to a project as a dependency it is not working.

```
jar cfe output/jar/my-java.jar Main src/pkg1/pkg0/*.class src/pkg1/*.class src/pkg2/*.class
```

My project structure is something like below structure

```
src
  pkg1
    A.java
    B.JAVA
    pkg0
     E.java
   pkg2
    C.java
    D.java
```

My Example code is something like

```
import pkg1.A;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.printMe("Hello World");
    }
}
```

error that I'm getting is:

> java pkg1 not exist
>   But in the editor(IntelliJ), it is not showing errors and also i'm able to import class but not package.

- import pkg1: showing red means error in the editor
- import pkg1.A: not showing red means no error in the editor

Note: I don't want to use maven.

Comment: Did you compile the classes before jar command? Could you unzip your jar and give us the structure?

Comment: testing: src/pkg1/A.class   OK

testing: src/pkg1/B.class   OK

testing: src/pkg2/C.class   OK

testing: src/pkg2/C.class   OK

testing: src/pkg1/pkg0/E$1.class   OK

testing: src/pkg1/pkg0/E.class   OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `unzip -t something.jar` shows the actual file structure of the jar file (zip). It is the same as the class structure of it (except that instead "`/`", a "`.`" is the separator).

In your case, the problem will be that `src` will be on the top level, and not `pkg1`. Either import `src.pkg1` (very dirty), or play a little bit more with the directories / jar flags.

Comment: To say what peterh says in different words: pkg1 and pkg2 must be at the root of the jar.

Comment: @BalzGuenat How can I check it is at root level or not.                                           the output of command unzip -t something.jar  is                     
 testing: src/pkg1/A.class OK testing: src/pkg1/B.class OK testing: src/pkg2/C.class OK testing: src/pkg2/C.class OK testing: src/pkg1/pkg0/E$1.class OK testing: src/pkg1/pkg0/E.class OK

Comment: Well, by looking at it. pkg1 is not at the root level because it's in src and src is at the root level.

Comment: @BalzGuenat Thanks. I removed the src and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

just call your method it automatic get path if you correctly put your jar in your current project.`project 1

```
 pkg com.test.demo
 class test{
 public static void m1(){
 System.out.println("project 1 in method 1 );
 }
 }
 in project 2 put jar of project 1
 pkg com.test.demo
 class Test1{
 public static void main(String...){
 System.out.println(test.m1())
 }


  }
```